# Conditional Formatting Based on Two Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have added some VBA coding to a document using Wingdings 2 `P` to create ticks.  I now want to add some conditional formatting so that if two cells have `P` (the tick symbol) then they turn a colour.  I can get it working in one cell but when I try to copy the formula it won't work. The formula I have put in is:

```
=AND(M6="P", N6="P")
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want a CF formula of the kind:

```
=AND($M6="P",$N6="P")
```

but it does somewhat depend upon what you would like formatted subject to the condition/s.